# Dynamic pdf filename to my visualforce page using iframe

Tags: apex, visualforce, pdf, iframe, blob.topdf

Here is my visualforce page code where i am displaying pdf in iframe but i am not able to set "file name" of this pdf,

```
<apex:page standardController="xyz__c" title="XYZ Form" action="{!Mergepdf}" 
        extensions="viewPDF" >

    <apex:slds />
    <b>Contract's PDF</b>
    <br/>
    <iframe src="data:application/pdf;base64,{!pdf}" height="1000px" width="100%" />
</apex:page>
```

this is what i have tried so far : **fileName = "testFileABC.pdf"** is not working for me.

Comment: What do you want to achieve by setting a file name?

Comment: Issue is : when user click on download button from pdf itself then file will be downloaded as "download.pdf" and i just want to rename this download.pdf to testFileABC.pdf